# Analytic function zero in the given disk

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

[image]I need to show that f(z)=0 for all z \in D(0,2).

From the analyticity of f in D(o,2), I know by Cauchy's theorem it's integral in |z|<2  is zeros. And clearly the integrand has a pole at 1/(n+1) for each n. Do I have to use Identity theorem to prove the desired result. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) and [Identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply both sides by $(n+1)/(2\pi i)$ to obtain
$$
   \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z)}{z-\frac{1}{(n+1)}}\,dz = 0.
$$
Then notice that by the Cauchy integral formula, the integral on the left is precisely $f(1/(n+1))$. So the zero set of $f(z)$ has an accumulation point inside $D(0,2)$, so it must be identically zero there.

Comment: A minor error (not affecting the validity of your solution) is absence of $1/(2\pi i)$.

Comment: Of course, thank you.

Comment: I had the f(1/n+1) but couldn't think of how to go by with the identity theorem. Thank you very much.